# Retrofit + RxJava: How to request for multiple request in order and assemble results in single Observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using RxJava + Retrofit.

For example, there are Article

```
public class Article {
    private Long articleId;
    private Long userId;
    private String image;
    private String text;
    ...
}
```

and User

```
public class User {
    private Long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String image;
    ...
}
```

And there are two sevices

- `Observable<List<User>> getUserByUserIds(List<Long> userIds)` and
- `Observable<List<Article>> listArticles(int pageIdx, int pageMax)`

I want to list 10 articles, and related author user information, assemble them into something like `Observable<List<Pair<Article, User>>>`, is it possible?

Comment: You are looking for [ZIP](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator

Comment: As others have mentioned use zip operator. example https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ZipExampleActivity.java

Comment: `listArticles` and `getUserByUserIds` are related, I have to make first call and get the article author user ids and then make the second call, zip operation fits for making synchronous unrelated requests.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
listArticles(int pageIdx, int pageMax)
.flatMapIterable(list->list)
.flatMap(article ->
     getUserByUserIds(article.userId)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .flatMapIterable(list->list),
     Pair::of
)
.toList();
```

However, the API is badly specced; Observables already have an innate ordering, no need to wrap everything in a List. getUserByIds - will it return a single user or multiple users? Why not have a single id to User method? Why aren't the IDs in the domain objects primitives? Do you expect to have items without IDs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `getUsersByUserIds` returns a list of users. I mean to make a single call for getting multiple users in order to save some traffic and server load. Is there any way I can make only two calls (one for getting articles and the other for getting related users)?

Comment: As for the ID attribute in the domain object not primitive, I just copied them from Hibernate reverse engineerings (yes from the server side), I didn't care that so much, I should do some research on it!

Answer (score 0):

One way could involve the use of the zip operator, which can combine multiple Observables together. You can read more [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html). Just pass the two observable to zip operator

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems zip operation is for making synchronous calls, it doesn't match my requirements.

Comment: Then you might want to use the compose operator providing a custom transformer which will fetch the ids from the first call and return it, so that the second call can make use of it